# key_down event of DateTimePicker

Tags: c#, datetimepicker, keydown

I am using this `DateTimePicker` control in my *UI*.

I want my control to behave like when user presses 'delete' or 'backspace' key the value displayed on `DateTimePicker` control should be an empty string.

Intially I managed by setting its `CustomFormat` property to empty string so that when *UI* loads it shows as null.

I am using `KeyDown` event to check/verify if user has enterd *Delete* or *Backspace* key.
Kindly help.

Manali

Comment: Do you want to get rid of "Select a Date" string? If yes, let me know i will delete my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you. You need to reset the format back to your desired format (Long, Short, Time, Custom), before you can get a new value. Do this in the ValueChanged event.

```
    private void dateTimePicker1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Delete || e.KeyCode == Keys.Back)
        {
            dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
            dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = " ";
        }
    }

    private void dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Long;
    }
```

When saving a value for the dateTimePicker, you can test if the dateTimePicker1.Format == DateTimePickerFormat.Custom, and then save the value as null in your database.

Enjoy!

Comment: Hey thanks a lot. It worked for me. Applying the same way, as in checking the format of the date and passing the value accordingly. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
  private void date_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if(e.Key == Key.Back || e.Key == Key.Delete)
                date.SelectedDate = null;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks Haris for the help. i applied the same logic.